# Fixed base cutoff wheel tool?

Tags: tools

I need a fixed base machine for a 2" to 3" diamond cutoff wheel. Most typical tools for cutoff wheels are angle grinder type hand held units. I need a fixed base machine, basically a motor with an arbor, ideally with speed control and can be clamped to a table.

Does such a tool exist? If so, what is it called?

Comment: If you're looking for the cutoff tool on an arm, the smallest I've seen are kits for adapting an angle grinder.  I haven't seen something similar for adapting something like a Dremel tool.  But I've seen miniature tools that are like a micro table saw that take blades and wheels that size.  They're used for modelling work and jewelry kinds of applications.  If that kind of thing would work, I can try to find some links.

Comment: @fixer1234 I know there are accessories for mounting an angle grinder, but I would really prefer to have a real fixed mount, not an angle grinder holder.

Comment: Do you need the wheel on an articulating arm, or can you use something with the wheel inside the base, like a miniature tile saw or table saw (that takes tiny diamond wheels)?

Comment: @fixer1234 It needs to be on an arm.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're in luck.  There's a good selection of tools called mini cut-off saws.  They take a blade or wheel of the size you're talking about.  Tiny saw blades and abrasive cutting wheels are readily available supply items.  Diamond wheels ought to be easy enough to find.  For example:

[MicroLux® Mini Miter / Cut-Off Saw from Micro-Mark](https://www.micromark.com/MicroLux-Mini-Miter-Cut-Off-Saw)

[image]

The picture shows it cutting wood, but it also cuts metal (and other stuff) using the appropriate wheels.

A Harbor Freight knock-off: https://www.harborfreight.com/2-in-mini-bench-top-cut-off-saw-62136.html

Here's one of many at Amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/TruePower-Speed-Cut-Off-2-Inch-colors/dp/B000VWHTUG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VWHTUG).

Many offerings on eBay: https://www.ebay.com/bhp/mini-cut-off-saw